# How to change font family or size for the text on ConfirmationOvelay

Tags: android

I want to change font family and text size on ConfirmationOverlay

Any idea? Does it change with system font?

```
  // Defaults to SUCCESS_ANIMATION
  new ConfirmationOverlay().showOn(myActivity);

  new ConfirmationOverlay()
     .setType(ConfirmationOverlay.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION)
     .setDuration(3000)
     .setMessage("Opening...")
     .setOnAnimationFinishedListener(new ConfirmationOverlay.OnAnimationFinishedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationFinished() {
             // Finished animating and the content view has been removed from myActivity.
         }
     }).showOn(myActivity);

  // Default duration is DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION_MS
  new ConfirmationOverlay()
     .setType(ConfirmationOverlay.FAILURE_ANIMATION)
     .setMessage("Failed")
     .setOnAnimationFinishedListener(new ConfirmationOverlay.OnAnimationFinishedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationFinished() {
             // Finished animating and the view has been removed from myView.getRootView().
         }
     }).showAbove(myView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the ConfirmationOverlay font and text size.
You could, however, create your own custom dialog.

See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/19129727)